# IPad 2 rollback to ios 5 from ios 6

Tags: ios, ipad

I'd like to rollback to IOS 5 from IOS 6 for an iPad 2.

I don't mind jail breaking if necessary but instructions would be appreciated.

Comment: Someone might be able to step in with a total answer, but if you don't get any answers - you might try showing your first attempt at jailbreaking (list the exact versions of software you have in mind for current iOS and jailbreak tools) and usually those narrow questions get quicker answers.

Comment: Thanks Mike I thought I might be a bit general here. There is an iOS version 6 problem with wifi that I want to investigate and could not see an answer rolling back OS versions on AskDifferent

Comment: In general, Jailbreaking is fiddly and each minor version has different steps. There's no easy button and since iTunes doesn't let you revert OS versions except in rare circumstances (and usually only in limited time windows) - what worked for one week stops working the next.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short Answer: It's probably not possible to downgrade your iPad 2

Long Answer: It is technically possible, but not without having SHSH blobs for both iOS 4 and iOS 5, which means having been jailbroken in the past on both of those versions, and having saved the .shsh files.